# Facebook android graph api How to get friends requests count?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile

Does anybody know how to get friend requests count with Graph API 2.0+.
The `/me/friendrequests` path doesn't work anymore:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) friend requests is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher", 
  "type": "OAuthException", 
  "code": 12
  }
}
```

And i can't choose lower API level in android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible anymore. There is no other API to use

Answer (score 0):

You can get friends count using:

-(void)getFriendList
{

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=friends.fields(first_name,last_name)" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary* friendsDic = [result objectForKey:@"friends"];
    NSArray *friends = [friendsDic objectForKey:@"data"];
    for (NSDictionary *friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"firstname %@",friend[@"first_name"]);
        NSLog(@"last name %@",friend[@"last_name"]);
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: I need to get count of requests to my friends, not my friends count.